A question about CMake and the compile order
I recently encountered this question:
I want to use antlr4 to do syntax analysis in my project, and the language used in my project is C++, I need to compile the link antlr-runtime, in order to meet the needs of multiple platforms, I choose to build from the source code, and put antlr-runtime in the third_party directory.
So in CMakelists part of the source code looks like this:
add_subdirectory(third_party)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)

The result I want is to compile the antlr4-runtime library in third_party and link it in src:
find_library(ANTLR4_LIB_PATH antlr4-runtime PATHS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
target_link_libraries(parser_obj ${ANTLR4_LIB_PATH})

But as a result, if I try to compile, I get a problem:
ld: library 'ANTLR4_LIB_PATH-NOTFOUND' not found

However, I found that there is already a library file in the /build/lib directory, so I can compile it the second time. Is there any way to make sure that antlr4 is compiled before find_library? Or make sure it's compiled in the right order?
I tried to compile and build the code of my project, but this steadily needed to be compiled twice before success. The first failed because the antlr4-current library file was not found, and the second could be compiled successfully

The workflow looks ok, cmake will normally resolve dependency order... you may be missing the subdirectory when linking.   The syntax is add_subdirectory(source_dir [binary_dir], where binary_dir is optional.  You may -- if you wish -- make this "build" but the docs state it'll match the subdirectory name if not provided, so chances are the copy you have is leftover from a previous build attempt and the new copy is landing in a subdirectory.

@tresf But I set lib dir in antlr4-runtime which is set(LIB_OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib).So in my expectation, lib library files should be correctly output to /build/lib, not subdirectories. So the ld should be able to link to the library file if it compiles correctly.

I agree, however that suggests you may have left important information about your problem out of the question.  You should include any portions of the code that are relevant to the error.  Ideally, a small reproducible code example.  Also, if you have spaces in your directory name, you may need double quotes around strings.
